# Unable to link cv2 in site-packages for pip to recognize

Tags: python, opencv, conda

I tried to build OpenCV v3.4.11. Tried to follow the following article [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-centos-7/). There were deviations as I have a Conda environment setup on which I'm trying to download.

All the pre-requisites for the opencv were also installed via dnf.

Here are the sequence of commands that I ran after cloning and going into the build directory that I ran which built successfully. All the paths to environments are verified.

```bash
cmake3 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/bin/python \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/include/python3.8 \
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/libpython3.8.so \
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/bin/python \
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/include/python3.8 \
-D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/libpython3.8.so \
-D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages \
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF ..
```

The configurations identified by the CMake was output as following:

```bash
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.11 =====================================
--   Version control:               3.4.11
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/opc/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     3.4.19-8-gf8525761
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2023-05-08T20:05:01Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.4.17-2136.318.7.1.el8uek.aarch64 aarch64
--     CMake:                       3.20.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    NEON FP16
--       required:                  NEON
--       disabled:                  VFPV3
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++11:                       YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 8.5.0)
-- 
...
...
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/bin/python (ver 3.8.15)
--     Libraries:                   /home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.15)
--     numpy:                       /home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.18.5)
--     install path:                /home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/opc/opencv_build/opencv/build
```

Was able to successfully run the `make install` command

Did the symlink for pkg-config and ran the get version command for opencv

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/opencv4.pc /usr/share/pkgconfig/
sudo ldconfig
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

The output was 3.4.11. Hence the installation was successful.

I'm not able to understand what to run as a substitution for this commands.

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Because nothing like the source link argument path exists now after installation and upon running `find` I can see the output as

```bash
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2
/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2
/home/opc/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/cv2
/home/opc/opencv_build/opencv/modules/python/package/cv2
/home/opc/opencv_build/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/install/python_loader/cv2
/home/opc/opencv_build/opencv/build/python_loader/cv2
```

Hence the cv2 actually got installed at **orion** environment. I can run the interpreter from orion env.

```py
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

Get a successfull output version as **3.4.11**. My problem right now is pip can't identify the package. Its important because one of my projects have the ConflictExceptions which is making it not run.

Upon running the command `pip check`. The output is:

```
mlprimitives 0.3.4 requires opencv-python, which is not installed.
```

Help me in linking the thing maybe. It will be very helpful. The output for the error is as follows:

```py
DistributionNotFound                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/opc/src/orion/main.ipynb Cell 5 in ()
----> 1 orion = Orion(
      2     pipeline='lstm_dynamic_threshold',
      3     hyperparameters=hyperparameters
      4 )

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/orion/core.py:64, in Orion.__init__(self, pipeline, hyperparameters)
     62 self._pipeline = pipeline or self.DEFAULT_PIPELINE
     63 self._hyperparameters = hyperparameters
---> 64 self._mlpipeline = self._get_mlpipeline()
     65 self._fitted = False

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/orion/core.py:54, in Orion._get_mlpipeline(self)
     51     with open(pipeline) as json_file:
     52         pipeline = json.load(json_file)
---> 54 mlpipeline = MLPipeline(pipeline)
     55 if self._hyperparameters:
     56     mlpipeline.set_hyperparameters(self._hyperparameters)

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlblocks/mlpipeline.py:213, in MLPipeline.__init__(self, pipeline, primitives, init_params, input_names, output_names, outputs, verbose)
    210 def __init__(self, pipeline=None, primitives=None, init_params=None,
    211              input_names=None, output_names=None, outputs=None, verbose=True):
--> 213     pipeline = self._get_pipeline_dict(pipeline, primitives)
    215     self.primitives = primitives or pipeline['primitives']
    216     self.init_params = init_params or pipeline.get('init_params', dict())

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlblocks/mlpipeline.py:137, in MLPipeline._get_pipeline_dict(pipeline, primitives)
    134     return pipeline
    136 elif isinstance(pipeline, str):
--> 137     return load_pipeline(pipeline)
    139 elif isinstance(pipeline, MLPipeline):
    140     return pipeline.to_dict()

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlblocks/discovery.py:282, in load_pipeline(name)
    264 def load_pipeline(name):
    265     """Locate and load the pipeline JSON annotation.
    266 
    267     All the pipeline paths will be scanned to find a JSON file with the given name,
   (...)
    280             A ``ValueError`` will be raised if the pipeline cannot be found.
    281     """
--> 282     pipeline = _load(name, get_pipelines_paths())
    283     if pipeline is None:
    284         raise ValueError("Unknown pipeline: {}".format(name))

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlblocks/discovery.py:198, in get_pipelines_paths()
    176 def get_pipelines_paths():
    177     """Get the list of folders where pipelines will be looked for.
    178 
    179     This list will include the values of all the entry points named ``pipelines``
   (...)
    196             The list of folders.
    197     """
--> 198     return _PIPELINES_PATHS + _load_entry_points('pipelines')

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlblocks/discovery.py:137, in _load_entry_points(entry_point_name, entry_point_group)
    135 for entry_point in entry_points:
    136     if entry_point.name == entry_point_name:
--> 137         paths = entry_point.load()
    138         if isinstance(paths, str):
    139             lookup_paths.append(paths)

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2516, in EntryPoint.load(self, require, *args, **kwargs)
   2509     warnings.warn(
   2510         "Parameters to load are deprecated.  Call .resolve and "
   2511         ".require separately.",
   2512         PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
   2513         stacklevel=2,
   2514     )
   2515 if require:
-> 2516     self.require(*args, **kwargs)
   2517 return self.resolve()

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2539, in EntryPoint.require(self, env, installer)
   2533 # Get the requirements for this entry point with all its extras and
   2534 # then resolve them. We have to pass `extras` along when resolving so
   2535 # that the working set knows what extras we want. Otherwise, for
   2536 # dist-info distributions, the working set will assume that the
   2537 # requirements for that extra are purely optional and skip over them.
   2538 reqs = self.dist.requires(self.extras)
-> 2539 items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
   2540 list(map(working_set.add, items))

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:827, in WorkingSet.resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    824 if not req_extras.markers_pass(req, extras):
    825     continue
--> 827 dist = self._resolve_dist(
    828     req, best, replace_conflicting, env, installer, required_by, to_activate
    829 )
    831 # push the new requirements onto the stack
    832 new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]

File ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:868, in WorkingSet._resolve_dist(self, req, best, replace_conflicting, env, installer, required_by, to_activate)
    866         if dist is None:
    867             requirers = required_by.get(req, None)
--> 868             raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    869     to_activate.append(dist)
    870 if dist not in req:
    871     # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency

DistributionNotFound: The 'opencv-python<4.7,>=3.4.0.12' distribution was not found and is required by the application.
```

Just for reference that opencv is present in my site-packages directory.
[image: ls command in my site-packages]

Comment: don't build it yourself. install it with `pip install opencv-python`. and avoid old versions. OpenCV v3.4 is old. and so is Python 2.7.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz. I want to install orion-ml, a python library for anomaly detection. Its requirements contain numpy<19.0. None of the latest OpenCV supports that version of numpy. I have numpy==18.5 right now. Hence building OpenCV. If I do pip install opencv-python==3.4.11. It fails to get build. Hence going for this option. Also it’s generally fine if there are conflicts. But there are Resolutions errors while trying to use that library

Comment: Have you tried installing all other dependencies of `orion-ml` manually and then doing ` pip install --no-deps orion-ml`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, yes I did. The orion-ml has been installed properly too. I can import it as a library. It's just that when I try to initialise the objects, it leads me ResolutionError which tells me that opencv is not installed.

Comment: Can you share the full error message? You can use the [edit] function to add it to your question

Comment: @FlyingTeller just added the stack trace for your reference.

Comment: try `mkdir ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/opencv_python-3.4.11.dist-info` followed by `touch ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/opencv_python-3.4.11.dist-info/METADATA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing `opencv` from source will not give you the package `opencv-python`, at least not from a `pkg_resources` perspective. In this case, the internal code when loading a pipeline checks for explicit dependencies and in this case, for an installed package `opencv-python`.

The workaround here is to fool `pkg_resources` into thinking that `opencv-python` is actually installed.

```
mkdir ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/opencv_python-3.4.11.dist-info
touch ~/.conda/envs/orion/lib/python3.8/opencv_python-3.4.11.dist-info/METADATA
```