# Can you "lie" to PIP to make it believe that packages are already installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to build a package for testing requirements.txt files for several versions of a program. Each version has different packages that would need to be installed in the environment beforehand. But to save space and not have to manage several versions I am trying to figure out the best way to handle this.

Originally I thought about making several virtual environments and installing the packages there, but even this still isn't optimal as there will be 5 venvs with different packages installed. The idea being that I can check requirements against constraints based on which version I am testing with.

End question is what would be the best way to do this // how can I make PIP believe that I have certain packages installed without actually having to install them?

Any thoughts/suggestions, I am open to any new ideas on it.

Comment: So you just want to see if your `requirements.txt` can actually be solved? Or you want to be able to install your project without `pip` installing its dependencies?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Yeah I just want to be able to see if a requirements.txt could be installed based on what the environment already has + constraints. I know that PIP has `--dry-run`, but I am having a devil of a time trying to mimic the required installed packages.

Comment: I think I have done something previously: You could create a folder `<package name>-<version>.dist-‌​info` in site-packages and create an empty `METADATA` file inside. This should fake `pip` into thinking that said package is actually installed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204104/unable-to-link-cv2-in-site-packages-for-pip-to-recognize#comment134404986_76204104

Comment: Were you able to make any progress?

Comment: I have made it into an answer for you to accept. That way it can be founbd easier in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a folder called

```
<package name>-<version>.dist-‌​info
```

in `site-packages` and create an empty `METADATA` file inside. This should fake `pip` into thinking that said package is actually installed

Comment: It's not even faking it, really. A package *named* `<package name>` *is* installed; it's just not the package the requirements file *intended* to be installed. This wouldn't work, though, if a requirement has a `--hash` option (without adjusting the hash, anyway).